# Call public function in another application

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

If I have a Windows Application WinApp that has a public function `pubFun`, how can I call it from a different windows application --> `WinApp.pubFun()` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both windows applications are Windows Forms (and not class libraries) by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't trivial, there's lots of ways to do it.

**I suggest using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)**, its a great framework that abstracts the communication logic and makes your inter-application communication work just like calling methods on an object.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything stopping you from extracting the logic out into a separate assembly which both applications can share?